# Model View Controller in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented

I have attempted to do Model View Controller in Python for learning. First, I am not sure if dictionaries are faster than lists for about N = 30 (20 to 40) items. Second, how maintainable is this design since I got abstraction but not very much encapsulation? The abstraction comes from abstracting towards to the domain classes.

The classes and their purposes:

- Table Model is a data class in the domain model.
- Total Price Model is an algorithm to compute the total price of Table Models.
- Table File handles File I/O of and sets the fields of Table Model.
- Table View handles user I/O which is currently command line.
- `main` is a driver program to run the code.

```
class TableModel:
    """
    Data Model of a table
    """
    def __init__(self, key :int, name: str, price_cents: int) -> None:
        """

        :param key: computer generated number
        :param name: name of this what
        :param price_cents: price in USD, in cents, of this what
        """
        self.key = key
        self.name = name
        self.price_cents = price_cents

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """
        Input: None \n
        Output: string to allow for debuging (print object out) \n
        """
        string = "key: " + str(self.key) + "\n"
        string = string + "name: " + self.name + "\n"
        string = string + "price_cents: " + str(self.price_cents) + "\n"
        return string


class TotalPriceModel:
    """
    Algorithm for total price
    """

    def total_price_cents(self, table_models:dict) -> int:
        """

        :param table_models: the table models
        Output: total price
        """
        cents = 0
        for key in table_models:
            cents = cents + table_models[key].price_cents
        return cents

class TableFile:
    """
    Models the file of table
    Note: this is a text file (for now anyways)
    """

    def __init__(self, table_models:[TableModel]) -> None:
        """
        :param table_models: dict, keys are str(table_model.key) and val are the talbe_model
        """
        self.table_models = table_models

    def to_file(self) -> None:
        """
        Input: None \n
        Output: None \n
        Note: puts info into file \n
        """
        file = open("save_file.txt", "r+")
        name = ""
        price_cents = ""
        key = ""
        for key in range(self.table_models):
            name = self.table_models[key].name
            price_cents = str(self.table_models[key].price_cents)
            key = str(self.table_models[key].key)
            file.write(name + "#" + price_cents + "#" + key)
        file.close()

    def from_file(self) -> None:
        """
        Input: None \n
        Output: None \n
        Note: puts file info into this \n
        """
        file = open("save_file.txt", "r+")
        name = ""
        price_cents = 0
        key = 0
        table_model = None

        #use gen so that the extra space is less
        for line in file.readlines():
            name = line.split("#")[0]
            price_cents = int(line.split("#")[1])
            key = int(line.split("#")[2])
            table_model = TableModel(key, name, price_cents)
            self.table_models.append(table_model)
        file.close()

    def add(self, what:TableModel) -> None:
        """
        :param what: what to add
        Output: None
        """
        self.table_models[str(what.key)] = what

    def remove(self, key:int) -> None:
        """
        :param key: key of the object to remove
        Output: None \n
        Note: if this not in the class, this results in nothing done
        """
        if key in self.table_models:
            del self.table_models[str(key)]

    def change(self, table:TableModel) -> None:
        """
        :param table: table that was changed using the computer  \n
        Output: None \n
        """
        self.table_models[str(table.key)] = table


class TableView:
    """
    User Input and User Output
    """

    def __init__(self, tables_model:dict) -> None:
        self.tables = tables_model

    def render(self) -> None:
        """
        Input: None \n
        Output: None \n
        Note: outputs to user
        """
        print("Table View")
        name = ""
        price_cents = ""
        for key in self.tables:
            name = self.tables[key].name
            price_cents = str(self.tables[key].price_cents)
            print(name + " " + price_cents)

    def change_event(self, table: TableModel) -> None:
        """
        :param table: table that was changed using the computer
        Output: None
        """
        self.tables[str(table.key)] = table

    def append_event(self, table: TableModel) -> None:
        """
        :param table: table that was added within the computer
        Output: None
        """
        self.tables[str(table.key)] = table

    def remove_event(self, table: TableModel) -> None:
        """
        :param table: table that was removed from the computer
        Output: None
        """
        if str(table.key) in self.tables:
            del self.tables[str(table.key)]


def main() -> None:
    """
    Input: None \n
    Output: None \n
    Note: Runs the code, can test using std output \n
    """

    table_model = TableModel(0, "Bob's Table", 0)
    table_view = TableView({})
    table_view.append_event(table_model)
    table_view.render()
    print(table_model)
    print("hello world")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Overview

You've done an excellent job:

- You did a good job partitioning code into functions
- You used meaningful names for classes, functions and variables
- You added documentation for the functions
- The `main` function makes it easy to see how to run some of the code

Here are some adjustments to consider, mainly for coding style.

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few style issues.

Consider using `with` to `open` a file.  This has the side benefit
of simplifying the code since there is no need to call `close`.

### Simpler

You can simplify the code in the `__str__` function using the `+=`
assignment operator:

```
def __str__(self) -> str:
    """
    Input: None
    Output: string to allow for debuging (print object out)
    """
    string = "key: " + str(self.key) + "\n"
    string += "name: " + self.name + "\n"
    string += "price_cents: " + str(self.price_cents) + "\n"
    return string
```

### Documentation

It is good practice to add a summary of the purpose of the code at top of the file.

Some of the docstrings have a literal `\n`, while others do not:

```
def from_file(self) -> None:
    """
    Input: None \n
    Output: None \n
    Note: puts file info into this \n
    """
```

If you don't need the `\n` for any reason, I recommend removing them.

Add more information for the `TableFile` class methods because I could not
figure out how to use them.  For example, it seems strange that the
`to_file` function uses `"r+"` for the file `open` mode to open a file for
writing.

### f-string

In some instances, using f-strings instead of concatenation may be cleaner.
For example, change:

```
        print(name + " " + price_cents)
```

to:

```
        print(f'{name} {price_cents}')
```

### Typo

"debuging" should be "debugging".

"talbe" should be "table".